# Using jyNI to access win32api file

Tags: java, python, outlook, jython, jyni

I have a java gui application that is feeding info into a python script using a python interpreter. This python script uses win32 to access a shared outlook folder. Separately, the python script works but my java application calls out an ImportError concerning the win32api.pyd file.

From this, I have tried troubleshooting by installing JyNI in order to account for Jython's inability to read C-extension files. However, I am still getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/python/modules/_weakref/ReferenceBackendFactory
```

Has anyone else had this issue or found a way to work around this issue?

Comment: awt looks like a front end problem.

Comment: Please share the versions of JyNI and Jython you are using. The missing class lets me suspect that Jython 2.7.0 was used, but JyNI requires 2.7.1. Windows was not supported before JyNI alpha 5. If the right version does not fix it, please share how you configure classpath and pythonpath. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50971980/jyni-eclipse-setup which looks like a somewhat similar issue.